# I'm having a trouble installing a .msi or .exe file in PowerShell set in my script

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I'm doing a script in PowerShell and I have to install the administration console. I have two installers, .msi and .exe for this one.

My script has to install it and it can't do it because the script stops when the installation GUI appears.

I was reviewing some webpages and I noticed something about silent mode so I try with this script

```
$pathvargs = {C:\_projects\xxxx\Current\Deployment\SupplementalInstalls\Administration\setup.exe /S /v/qn }
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $pathvargs
```

but a Windows Installer popup thrown explaining me how are the commands for a windows installation, so I try with these scripts too:

```
$product = [WMICLASS]"\\MyMachine\ROOT\CIMV2:win32_Product"
$product.Install("C:\_projects\xxxx\Current\Deployment\SupplementalInstalls\Administration\AdminConsole.msi")

Start-Process -FilePath "C:\_projects\xxxx\Current\Deployment\SupplementalInstalls\Administration\setup.exe" -ArgumentList "/S /v/qn"
```

Same windows installation poop up appears.

I can't install the administration console using my script, can anyone help me?

Comment: Please show the exact error(s) you're getting. Also, what "administration console"? Which commandline options does either your `setup.exe` actually support? Did you try `msiexec AdminConsole.msi /qn`?

Comment: Personally I like `msiexec AdminConsole.msi /qb-!` so that progress can be monitored, but there's no cancel option, and there's no 'OK' button to click at the end of the installation.

Comment: Works with msiexe /i xxxx /qb, Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you have the MSI, do it through `MSIExec.exe` in Powershell, i.e.:

```
Invoke-Expression "msiexec.exe /i 'C:\_projects\xxxx\Current\Deployment\SupplementalInstalls\Administration\AdminConsole.msi' /quiet /norestart /L 'install.log'" -ErrorAction Stop
```

Comment: Yeah, that works excellent!, do you know how can I do it with .exe ? Thanks!

Comment: The Exe would need to have it's own command line parameters to be able to be executed the same. Typically, MSI's are geared towards IT administration installs, since you can leverage `MSIExec`, compiled executables are kind of at the whim of the developer to include command line functionality.

Comment: No problem! Enjoy!